# Localize this PayPal link: webscr

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, localization

I'm using a wordpress plugin that redirect my buyers to:

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

but I'd like to redirect them to an Italian localized page so
they can feel at home in the PayPal Italian page.

the snippet of code is:

```
$code = '<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="ppform'.$randval.'" method="post">';
```

and moreover the buyer receive this:

Product: name
Amount: 10.00 EUR
Buyer Email: email@email
Download Link: link

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

With Payments Standard you can use the [currency_code](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/currency_codes/#id09A6G0U0GYK) parameter to set the currency used during checkout and displayed on the PayPal pages.

You can use the lc parameter to set a locale code as well, which effects the language on the PayPal checkout pages.  In your case it seems you can accomplish what you want by adding the following to your button code / standard checkout code.

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="IT" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR" />
```

Comment: I do not understand where and how implement your code. I simply need to make www paypal com/cgi-bin/webscr redirect to an italian page. Thanks.

Comment: That's what I'm telling you how to do.  Can you provide a sample of your PayPal button code?